# Lucene skips years when NumericRangeQuery on dates

Tags: java, lucene

We are running a Lucene query for the date range 20000101 to 20070531, but Lucene only returns documents with a publicationDate between 20000101-20000701 and 20070101-20070531.  Lucene skips several years.  When running different date sets the results are similar.

Full insert code:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("pageNumber", article.getPageNumber(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
doc.add(new NumericField("publicationDate", 8, Field.Store.YES, true).setIntValue(Integer.parseInt(article.getPublicationDate())));
doc.add(new Field("headline", article.getHeadline(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("text", article.getText(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("fileName", article.getFileName(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("mediaType", article.getMediaType(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("mediaSource", article.getMediaSource(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("overLap", article.getMediaType(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("status", article.getMediaType(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
```

Document count code:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
    Directory index = new SimpleFSDirectory(new File(LUCENE_INDEX_DIRECTORY));
    IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(index);

    Query sourceQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("mediaSource", source));
    QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "text", analyzer);
    Query textQuery = queryParser.parse(terms);
    Query dateRangeQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("publicationDate", startDate, endDate, true, true);

    BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    booleanQuery.add(sourceQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    booleanQuery.add(textQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    booleanQuery.add(dateRangeQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

    TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();
    searcher.search(booleanQuery, collector);

    System.out.println("start: " + startDate);
    System.out.println("end: " + endDate);
    System.out.println("total: " + collector.getTotalHits());

    String hitCount = String.valueOf(collector.getTotalHits());
    searcher.close();
    reader.close();
    analyzer.close();
    return hitCount;
```

Full document list:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
    Directory index = new SimpleFSDirectory(new File(LUCENE_INDEX_DIRECTORY));
    IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(index);

    Query sourceQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("mediaSource", source));
    QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "text", analyzer);
    Query textQuery = queryParser.parse(terms);
    Query dateRangeQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("publicationDate", startDate, endDate, true, true);

    BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    booleanQuery.add(sourceQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    booleanQuery.add(textQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    booleanQuery.add(dateRangeQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();
    searcher.search(booleanQuery, collector);

    Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("publicationDate", SortField.INT));

    if (collector.getTotalHits() > 0) {
        TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(booleanQuery, collector.getTotalHits(), sort);

        int i = 0;
        for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs) {
            ArrayList<String> resultRow = new ArrayList<String>();
            Document doc = searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
            resultRow.add(String.valueOf(i));
            resultRow.add(doc.get("publicationDate"));
            resultRow.add(doc.get("mediaSource"));
            resultRow.add(doc.get("fileName"));
            resultRow.add(doc.get("headline"));
            resultRow.add(doc.get("pageNumber"));
            ql.results.put(String.valueOf(i), resultRow);
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        ArrayList<String> resultRow = new ArrayList<String>();
        resultRow.add("0");
        resultRow.add("0");
        resultRow.add("0");
        resultRow.add("0");
        resultRow.add("0");
        resultRow.add("0");
        ql.results.put("0", resultRow);
    }
```

Truncated results (last 10 of 2058 documents):

```
20021231   Iraq Belongs on the Back Burner
20021231    With Missionaries Spreading, Muslims' Anger Is Following
20021231    WHITE HOUSE CUTS ESTIMATE OF COST OF WAR WITH IRAQ
20021231    Bring Back the Draft
20040101    Pakistani Leader's New Tactic: Persuasion
20040101    What We Will Do in 2004
20040101    Ethnic Morass Bogs Down Afghan Talks On Charter
20040101    U.S. Hunts Terror Clues in Case of 2 Brothers
20040101    Giving Up Those Weapons: After Libya, Who Is Next?
20040101    An Odd Sight in Iran as Aid Team Tents Go Up: The U.S. Flag
```

Comment: you should use `FSDirectory.open` rather than `new SimpleFSDirectory`

Comment: how do you know that some years are skipped?

Comment: Thanks.  Changing to FSDirectory.open doesn't change the output.

Comment: We have another block of code that returns the actual document details (publicationDate, text, etc.).  The counts are the same between methods.  Even if we change the date range to 20020101-20040101 Lucene will return all of the documents from 2002, skip 2003 and then return documents from January 1, 2004.  It is very strange.

Comment: can you paste some code that shows the problem? (the indexing and the searching parts, with explicit document creation and calls to IndexWriter.add)

Comment: Added the requested code and some example results.  If I change the date range to start on 20030101 I get results for 2003.  Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that NumericRangeQueries do not work correctly.  Using a RangeQuery with string values corrects the problem.